# PHP class, html forum, print $_POST Array on page

Tags: php, html, oop

i am beginner php programmer, iv been trying to create a small program that takes input from a forum and then after submission i want it to be printed on the screen. simple and easy i thought, iv been trying  and suspiciously it seems to work fine for 1 text field, when i added the remaining 2 text fields called [fam][user] my code stops returning the content to the screen. also i started to recieve an error of an unindex array, therefore i had to use isset to counter this problem, and also, why does my code call the destructor although i never implicitly set my destructor. i dont know how to ask these questions because the errors arent consistent.

- code doesnt print my [name][fam][user]
- code prints [name] when everything about [fam][user] are ommited from the code.
- -code sometimes called the destructor
- -code doesnt clear html previous input(e.g, when working with the one text field, lets say i input the [name] john, and click submit it
  displays submit, then,i refresh the page, and the name john is still
  displayed, why doesnt the destructor clear the memory of name from my
  submission.

  ```
       <form class="nameform" action="book.php" method="post">
           <input type="text" name="Name" value="1">
           <input type="text" name="Fam" value="2">
           <input type="text" name="User" value="3">
           <input type="button" name="submit" value="Submit">
       </form>
  ```

  ```
        private $name; private $familyName; private $userName;
        function __construct($names,$familyNames,$userNames)
        {
          $this->name = $names;
          $this->familyName = $familyNames;
          $this->userName = $userNames;
        }
        function getName()
        {
          return $this->name;
        }
        function getFamilyName()
        {
          return $this->familyName;
        }
        function getUserName()
        {
          return $this->userName;
        }
        public function __destruct()
        {
          echo "destroyed again";
          $this->name;
          $this->familyName;
          $this->userName;
        }
      }

      if(!isset( $_POST["Name"])||!isset($_POST["Fam"])||!isset($_POST["User"]))
      {
          echo "Please fill in the data";
      } else {
        $p1 = new Person($_POST["Name"],$_POST["Fam"],$_POST["User"]);
        print $p1->getName();
        print $p1->getFamilyName();
        print $p1->getUserName();
        print_r($_POST);
      }

      // $n = $_POST["Name"];
      // $f = $_POST["Fam"];
      // $u =  $_POST["User"];
      // $p1 = new Person($_POST["Name"],$_POST["Fam"],$_POST["User"]);


   ?>
  ```

Comment: 1. Destructor is always called, no matter if you overwrite it or not. How you know it's (not)called? 2. Form inputs persist on refresh - it's browser features, not your code, hitting hard refresh button should fix it. 3. What exactly error and where you get?

Comment: @Justinas im not getting any error, just not receiving the output that i desire,
 print $p1->getName();
      print $p1->getFamilyName();
      print $p1->getUserName();
these are not printing after i click submit
then why do i need a destructor, i had written the echo"destroyed again" and it would call the destructor, its not calling it anymore. i tried the hard refresh, still have input data in there

Comment: @Justinas - actually in this case it is not always called, if the class is never instantiated because the if passes, then no destruct because there is no object.  But it is always called when you have the object...  One could confuse that with it sometimes not being called.

Comment: `echo"destroyed again"` is not destructor. `Person::__destruct()` is destructor.

Comment: Can you show us how your `Person` looks like? Also, do you have error reporting turned on? Try using `if (isset($_POST["Name"], $_POST["Fam"]), $_POST["User"]))`

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix makes sense thanks

Comment: @Justinas that didnt work i got an error from ",". anyways still not getting any data printed.

Answer (score 0):

> code doesnt print my [name][fam][user]

You never echo them out of the destuctor

```
  public function __destruct()
  {
    echo "destroyed again";
    $this->name; //<---- does nothing
    $this->familyName;
    $this->userName;
  }
```

So I am not sure what this is supposed to do.  You have them down at the bottom

```
  print $p1->getName();
  print $p1->getFamilyName();
  print $p1->getUserName();
```

But the only thing you'll get from the destruct method is

```
 "destroyed again"
```

And you will only see that if everything in the form is set. Which it always is when the form is submitted, because type `text` is always submitted with its form.

Which brings me to this, you should be checking `empty` instead of `isset` there

```
if ('POST' === $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) { //check if POST
    if(empty($_POST["Name"])||empty($_POST["Fam"])||empty($_POST["User"])){
        echo "Please fill in the data";
    } else {
        $p1 = new Person($_POST["Name"],$_POST["Fam"],$_POST["User"]);
       print $p1->getName();
       print $p1->getFamilyName();
       print $p1->getUserName();
       print_r($_POST);
    }
}
```

Note that anything **falsy** will be empty, `false`, `[]`, `''`, `0`, `'0'`, `null` etc.

I don't know if this solves all of you problems, but these things could produce some of the behaviour you are experiencing.

Another more advance way to check these is like this:

```
if ('POST' === $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) { //check if POST
     $post = array_filter( $_POST, function($item){
           return strlen($item); //any thing of a length of 0 is removed
     });

     if(count($post) != count($_POST)){
           foreach(array_diff_key( $_POST, $post)  as $missing=>$empty) {
                  echo "Please fill in $missing\n";
           }
     }else{
       $p1 = new Person($_POST["Name"],$_POST["Fam"],$_POST["User"]);
       print $p1->getName();
       print $p1->getFamilyName();
       print $p1->getUserName();
       print_r($_POST);
    }
}
```

Output

```
Please fill in Name
Please fill in Fam
```

You can test it online [Here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/91b746a4010277567dd38faf32ea344a11cf13bc)

Cheers!